# Autoit numpad "8" vs. "regular" 8

Tags: autoit

I broke the letter "I" on my laptop keyboard and rely on a hack to type i's:

```
HotKeySet("8", "_b")
HotKeySet("9", "_bb")

While 1
     Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func _b()
     Send("i")
  EndFunc


  Func _bb()
     Send("I")
  EndFunc
```

However, I noticed that typing the "Numpad" 8 results in 8, not an "i".

How do I update the script above to make the "Numpad" 8 result in an "I"???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HotKeySet("8", "_b")
HotKeySet("9", "_bb")
```

It's not a 'numpad 8' but standard '8'.
Numpad 8 is "{NUMPAD8}".

Try with:

```
HotKeySet("{NUMPAD8}", "_b")
HotKeySet("{NUMPAD9}", "_bb")

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func _b()
    Send("i")
EndFunc

Func _bb()
    Send("I")
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 2):

As VixinG Said its {NUMPAD8}

you can look for Keys supported by Autoit in the Appendix "Send Key list" of The Autoitv3 Documentatiom.